# How to make a rtsp server with gstreamer on Windows?

Tags: windows, gstreamer, rtsp

I am trying to create a RTSP server to stream the feed from my webcam but am encountering some issues.

I already installed the lastest version of Gstreamer-devel for Windows 7 with all the plug-ins.

I have been able to achieve this on LINUX with this C++ script :

```
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(factory,
                            "v4lsrc device="/dev/video0"
                            "! video/x-raw", format=(string)I420, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)15/1"
                            "! x264enc" cabac=true tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true sliced-threads=true threads=0 speed-preset=1 "
                            "! rtph264pay pt=96 name=pay0 "
                            ")");
```

I can also visualize the webcam feed on WINDOWS through command line, with the command "gst-launch-1.0 ksvideosrc device-index=0 ! autovideosink"

However, I am unable to do so on Windows through Visual Studio Express 2013.
I have tried to replace "v4lsrc ..." with "ksvideosrc device-index=0" and to remove all other options to no avail.
I have been able to compile the solution but cannot see the feed on VLC media player

Would you possibly know how to rectify this so I can obtain the webcam feed on Windows?  Are there any compatibility issues or things I should be aware of to enable operation with Windows?

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point would be to verify that the pipeline you're using in the factory is functioning properly. Try making a similar pipeline on the command line to verify that data flows end-to-end : 
eg.

`gst-launch-1.0 ksvideosrc device-index=0 ! ! video/x-raw", format=(string)I420, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)15/1 ! x264enc cabac=true tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true sliced-threads=true threads=0 speed-preset=1 ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! fakesink dump=true`

This pipeline will capture from the device and dump the rtp data to stdout. Once this is verified then it's worth looking into whats going on with the rtsp server side of things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Sorry to answer only now. I tried it this week-end. In the cmd, I have the error "WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not parse caps "video/x-raw, \format=(string)I420, \ width=(int)320,\ height=(int)240,\ framerate=(fraction)15/1\"

Comment: The previous message is not fully writte, I don't know why.

Comment: I remove the " aftervideo/x-raw" and I have an other error message.

Comment: Setting pipeline to paused…
Pipeline is live and does not need Preroll…
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline : pipeline0/ GstKsVideoSrc: ksvideoSrc: ksvideosrc0: Internal data flow error
Additional debug info : 
gstbasesrc.c<2943>: gst_base_src_loop <>: /GstPipeline: pipeline0/GstKsVideoSrc: ksvideosrc0: 
Streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated <-4>
ERROR: pipelinedoesn’t want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to paused/ready/null …
Freeing pipeline…

Comment: It looks like ksvideosrc doesn't support video/x-raw I420 so you'll have to perform the colorspace conversion. Try the pipeline: `gst-launch-1.0 ksvideosrc device-index=0 ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! fakesink dump=true`  and see if that works.

Comment: It doesn't work too. I have almost the same message but this time the pipeline is playing and there is a new clock :

paused/ live / not need Preroll/

setting pipeline to playing...

/new clock: GstSystemClock

/Error (same than before)

/Additional debug info: same than before

/streaming task paused, reason not-linked <-1>

/Execution ended after 0:00:01.21...

paused/ready/null/freeing

Comment: I don't know why I have this error =/

What do you mean by "you'll have to perform the colorspace conversion" ?

What can I try to go ahead?

Comment: Using `gst-inspect-1.0 ksvideosrc`, it looks like this element can only produce src pads with raw video in various flavors of RGB formatting. Looking at `gst-inspect-1.0 x264enc`, this element's sink pads require a different raw format. So this requires an additional element in the gstreamer pipeline to make this conversion. I had hoped that the decodebin element would take care of this, but maybe you need to add `videoconvert` element after `decodebin`. : `gst-launch-1.0 ksvideosrc device-index=0 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! fakesink dump=true`

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! I understand better what I do =D 

I think it works with videoconvert ! I have a flow of hexadecimals in the command line. This is what we want with "fakesink dump=true" if I got it.

Comment: It works in my program too with

'gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(factory, "ksvideosrc device-index=0 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay pt=96 name=pay0");' 

There is just 4 sec of latency and it's gray during a few seconds but it works!

Comment: @Clem's where you able to find a better solution?